# Passing data between services in Angular 2 only works with @Host()?

Tags: angular

After reading over [this example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) from the docs, I noticed the components don't actually see the other's changes to the service data unless the child obtained the shared service by doing:

```
@Host() private _myService: MyService
```

Instead of doing the suggested:

```
private _myService: MyService
```

I had to state the providers [ MyService ] in the parent class and not in the child class for this to work.

Now, although this does work, the main question is why doesn't it work as done in the doc example?

Note: the @Host() method doesn't work for grand-child components which is what I really need.

I want the (grand)parent to be able to detect observable changes from the service based on additions from either the child or grandchild components.

There is a work-around, but its not pretty...

ParentComponent constructor:

```
private _myService: MyService
```

ChildComponent constructor:

```
@Host() private _myService: MyService
```

ChildComponent HTML:

```
<grand-child [_myService]="_myService"></grand-child>
```

GrandChildComponent variable:

```
_myService: MyService
```

This works, the service is shared between all components, but it's not pretty and I'm not sure if its even good practice.

Any ideas why this isn't working as stated in the docs?

---

Added plunk example of this not working:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Imm7MQLuQR8HhNh3Kbw7?p=preview

Comment: Strange if u fix it to a parent compontent then the service is available for the whole component tree. Try putting service in ngmodule and see if that is available for whole cmp tree